# MongoDB and Windows Forms using POCO

Tags: c#, forms, mongodb, poco

I would like to be able to use Windows Form with MongoDB while using POCO, mainly because it's easy to obtain values from MongoDB in string literals. The only problem I'm having is that POCO takes blank entries from the Windows forms as a blank string (""), so that when using InsertOneAsync(), i see the fields with values "".

This isn't generally desirable, mainly because:

1. It takes up space in the collection, and
2. I'd like to make queries using the Windows Form itself. If the queries have "", in one field while in the Mongo document it's not a "" (a non-blank string), then it will return nothing, because the strings don't match.

Below is my code for importing the document from Windows Form to MongoDB.. Some other issues I've had:

- Using "null" just creates a field with value null. My goal is simply not to create the field.
- the code i have for ZIP converts the "null" to a "0". I'd like to change that so its just not entering the field when the windows form entry is blank.

  ```
      var person = new Person
      {
          lastName = textBox1.Text.ToUpper(),
          firstName = textBox8.Text.ToUpper(),
          address = new Address
          {
              streetAddress = textBox4.Text.ToUpper(),
              city = textBox5.Text.ToUpper(),
              state = comboBox1.Text.ToUpper(),
              ZIP = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) ? null : textBox7.Text)
          }
      };

      var client = new MongoClient();
      var database = client.GetDatabase("dataBase");
      var col = database.GetCollection<Person>("addressBook");

      await col.InsertOneAsync(person);
  ```

P.S. this is my first question on here, so please let me know if I'm not providing enough information.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a little soul searching, it seems POCO is not ideal for multi-field requests.

The best way to make a request is to use a BsonDocument generic type, and then convert the found document to the generic type "person". Example Code is posted here:

```
var doc = new BsonDocument(); // Creating a filter for me in BSON

var lastName = textBox1.Text;
if (lastName != "") // Is my string in the Windows Form empty?
    doc.Add("lastName", lastName); // If not, add me to the filter.

var firstName = textBox8.Text;
if (firstName != "")
    doc.Add("firstName", firstName);
```

If the string literal is not empty, then it adds the field and its corresponding value to the BsonDocument that will be used as the filter.

```
var doc = await colBson.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
// Find me, but as a BSON document.
```

The document is then found as a BsonDocument.

```
var person = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(doc);
// Convert me into a <Person> generic type.
```

From here you can do as you wish with a "Person" typed class.

Please let me know if I'm unclear on anything.